# UIImageView backgroundColor colorWithPatternImage not showing

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm having an issue with UIImageView that's not quite making sense to me.  I want to set the image of the UIImageView and have it appear above the patterned image I've set to the background.  This occurs correctly if the background color is a standard color: [UIColor whiteColor], but as soon as set it to a patternImage the background becomes completely transparent.  This is kind of frustrating.  I can get around it by creating another view, setting the backgroundColor of it to a patternImage, and then adding the UIImageView as a subview, but that's creating an extra view that should be unnecessary, IMO.  Here's my code:

```
UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:_standardRect];
view.image = _connectIcon;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"background.jpg"]];
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
return view;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this works on iOS 5.1:

```
view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"background.jpg"]].CGColor;
```

However, the bug is gone on iOS 6.